# phonegap - serve javascript ads from custom ad server?

Tags: cordova, ads

Is it possible to embed my own javascript ad tags in an html5 app packaged with phonegap? I've done a lot of googling and most users use admob however I want to serve my own ads. Ideally I'd just embed the ad tags from our adserver which them renders an iframe to the target ad content.

I'm not 100% sure how phonegap works but to my knowledge it's just a native app with a web browser component serving the apps html content. So in theory I could paste in any html/javascript and it would function just as if the mobile safari/chrome was browsing the same content on a web server.

Has anyone tried this or know if it violates Apple/Google TOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the ads don't require PHP or any other server side software then it should work fine. I've done it personally with Javascript ad code before without an issue.

Both Apple and Google allow you to show ads in your apps

Comment: No problem :) If you need more help feel free to give me a shout